# Hiding Null Records on Command

Tags: ms-access, button, radio-button

My question is fairly straight forward and hopefully simple.

I've got a database that has a long list of part numbers, and some items without part numbers. What i'd like to do is have a command button or Radio button that when activated, hides these null records, and when pressed again, shows them once more.

I can give more detail if needed

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can filter or query, but the details vary according to where you want to display the data, so please post some more information.

Comment: Sorry about that - The details will be displayed on a Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using the Filter (same as using of out-of-the-box filtering capability from the Access/Office menu):

Setup:

- **Table (e.g. Parts):**

[image]

- **Form (PartsForm):**

[image]
[image]
[image]

- **Event handler for the Checkbox (OnClick):**

  ```
  Private Sub DisplayAllFilter_Click()

  Me.Filter = ""

  If Me.DisplayAllFilter.Value = False Then
      Me.Filter = "[PartNumber] is not null"
      Me.FilterOn = True
  Else
      Me.FilterOn = False
  End If

  End Sub
  ```

Result would be something like these:
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is Awesome @Igor Turman

Thanks a ton, exactly what I needed!

Comment: Sorry, It all works except how do you Change the Filter On Load in ACCESS 2003?

The real problem is that it gets rid of the Null values, but doesnt refresh them back

Comment: For Access 2003, please try the updated code (see above). This does work for 2007 and, hopefully, works for 2003 as well. Additionally, you may need to add _Me.FilterOn = False_ to the Page OnLoad event